# Variable window PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, workspace

I would like to open and fix in my Pycharm standard window the Work space in order to see the created variables and analyse them (like the attached screenshot). What should I do?

I looked for an answer in Jet brain guides but I didn't find a solution.